# Using Angular to Display a List of Images using a Blob

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show a list of photos using a `blob`, but it is not displaying any of the images. I created and provided a link to an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjnjaj). What have I missed that can be used to resolve this issue?

I'm using this code for downloading an image :

```
getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.http.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

and retrieve the images using a service:

```
CreateImageBlob(imageUrl: string): void {
   this.productService.getImage(imageUrl).subscribe(
     (val)=>{
       this.getImageFromService(val)
     },
     response => {
      console.log("POST in error", response);
    },
    () => {
      console.log("POST observable is now completed.");
    });
}
```

Using this to create a new file:

```
public getImageFromService(image:Blob){
  let reader=new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load",()=>{
    this.imageBlobUrl=reader.result;
  },false);

  if(image) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(image)
  }
}
```

and finally the template for displaying the image looks like:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can not accept that essential parts of a question (or answer) are outsourced, for the simple reason that we don't know how long the link will stay alive, and that we don't want to have half questions in 2 years with nobody able to catch anything about it. So please, include everything necessary for us to understand your problem (the so-called [MCVE]), **in the question itself**, and not behind a link.

Comment: @Kaiido i edit the question . please help me for solve this problem

Comment: I'm not an angular ninja and may not be the one the most prone to help you, but note that you don't need this asynchronicity in `getImageFromService`. It could be rewritten to `getImageFromService(image:Blob) { this.imageBlobURL = new URL.createObjectURL(image); }`. This may or may not fix your problem, but will anyway make it simpler and use less memory, as a rule of thumb, you don't need readAsDataURL unless you know you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few things I would suggest to get you to a solution. What you're doing is invoking an observable, subscribing to the result, and applying a Subscription to a binding of `src`.  Fundamentally this won't work, and you at least need to drop the `subscribe`, use the `map` pipe operator, and the `async` pipe based on your current code.

1. You should read up on how to use Angular's `async` pipe, which would allow you to do something like: `<img [src]="src$ | async">` and have it bind the response properly - @see [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)
2. You should read up on `Observables`, specifically `BehaviorSubject`- @see [`Understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject`](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0)
3. You should read up on `DomSanitizer` when binding - @see [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)
4. Finally, I would give an isolated component the job to render the image

[`Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epjkhd?embed=1&file=src/app/display-image.component.ts) is a simple (naive) example:)

Comment: Hi @Mr-Programer when you use the `DomSanitizer` you're saying that you trust the content you are displaying.  It is a way to show information that Angular would not by default.  Based on your use case this is the way to bind an image source.  If you remove the `DomSanitizer` in the example you'll see the images disappear.